# Increase disk space without losing any data

Tags: disk

I have a server running webmin/virtualmin in debian 7 with one 80GB hard drive. I want to increase disk space adding a second 1TB disk, but without losing any data as I'm hosting a few websites.
Any method and help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little confused, If you add a new drive to your machine, and format the new drive to work with your OS then you should be able to just add data too it. Are you wanting to swap your data to the new drive?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my webmin/virtualmin installation adds new website directories only in home folder. So I need a way to extend capacity of home. The solution of @gyropyge below is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you chose to use the word ADD as opposed to REPLACE, it is my impression you wish to add the 1 tb drive to your system without removing the 80 gb.  Most people wish to replace, but I can see why, if you are hosting webspace, you would not want the service interruption.

To merely add the drive, lease connect the drive to to your system and open [GPARTED](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted).  When you have located the drive, select to format the 1 tb drive as ext4 and set the mount point as something which will be recognized as part of your system, such as Home/Terabyte.  When you are done with your configuration for this drive, be sure to click the checkmark to engage your settings.  When it is complete, your new TB drive should appear as a folder in the directory structure probably in alphabetical order between Pictures and Videos.

You don't actually need to configure the drive to appear to be a folder in your directory structure, but it will appear rather seamless.

Comment: It worked great! Thank you :) I couldn't make it with gparted in debian, so i edited the fstab file where I changed location of new drive and automount.

Comment: I have a few permission problems with my websites located on new drive. I had to change PHP script execution mode under website options to Apache mod_php from FCGid or I get 500 error in browser.